# integrating amazon fling sdk and whisperplay sdk to android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a wifi remote control using `connect-sdk` project (https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android).

it says to download the amazon sdk, so I'm following amazon tutorial, which in there it says to download `WhisperPlay` lib:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fling/setting-up-your-amazon-fling-development-environment-for-android.html#adding-additional-libraries-generic-android-only

but I can't find it anywhere on amazon nor on google - **where can I download `Whisperplay.jar` file**?
is it still available or it is deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is download the amazon fling sdk from the site https://developer.amazon.com/docs/apps-and-games/sdk-downloads.html#fling

After downloading the sdk, extract the zip file to a folder. Then in the folder, navigate to
**Path to extracted sdk\android-sdk\lib\android**. Inside, you will find the WhisperPlay.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I helped implement this library in 2013-2016. Feel free to ping with any questions, or if you would like help triaging any bugs related to the Whisperplay stack. There will be  many.

https://github.com/Unofficial-Whisperplay-Fling-Helpline/wp/issues
gh:ubuvoid